# PHPSpreadsheet 1.15.0, access cell by name

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have an Excel "Template" with some named cells as "student" for example, which is the cell coordinates B2
I used to use PHPSpreadsheet and access some cells by: `$worksheet->getCell('student');`

It worked until the last 1.15.0 version, which returns me this error: `"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCell() on null"`
In my Excel file this named cell is `"=Feuil1!$B$5"`, but if I try to manually change it to `"=Feuil1!B5"` I have some stranges behaviours, the named cell place change for C5, or B4, etc...

I really need to access cells by name by I don't know how to do this with the 1.15.0 version of PHPSpreadSheet...

Thanks!

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue. 1.15.0 introduced some breaking changes to the way named ranges are handled. As far as I can tell, it's no longer possible to access a named cell using getCell() (but I'd be really happy to be proved wrong).

Comment: I found a solution :

    $pattern = '/.+?(!)/';
    $myCellRange = str_replace('$', '', preg_replace($pattern, '', $spreadsheet->getNamedRange('CELL_NAME')->getRange()));

With this I can have the range of a named cell. It's not very beautiful but it works. :)